# String Manipulation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, string

I am having a lengthy string which contains alphabets and a special character like "|". i need to split this strings based on the "|" delimiter and store the individual string in to an array. Is there any string function which helps us to do the same.?

Thanks,
Shibin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need `componentsSeparatedByString:`

```
NSString *string = @"hello|how|are|you";
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]; 
NSLog(@"array: %@", array);
```

Output:

```
array: (
    hello,
    how,
    are,
    you
    )
```